# White text on white background in tablet version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-styles

I cannot see what's wrong with my layout. In Phone it shows black text in a white background. But in the tablet version, it is all white.

I don't want to set `textColor` to each `TextView`.

Here is my layout for `StepMasterActivity` (it's a raw design yet):

layout/activity_step_master.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.github.alexpfx.udacity.nanodegree.android.baking_app.step.StepMasterActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/step_master_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >


    </FrameLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

layout-sw600dp/activity_step_master.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.github.alexpfx.udacity.nanodegree.android.baking_app.step.StepMasterActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha="250"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/step_list_fragment"
                android:name="com.github.alexpfx.udacity.nanodegree.android.baking_app.step.master.steps.StepListFragment"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                />
        </FrameLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
            />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/step_master_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the layout below is same for tablet and phone version:

item_ingredient.xml  (**Ingredients** recyclerview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_ingredient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_internal_views"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        tools:text="Nutella or other chocolate-hazelnut spread"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

item_step.xml (**Steps** recycler view)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_has_video"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_internal_views"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_videocam_black_24dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_has_video"
        android:id="@+id/text_step_short_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_internal_views"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Subtitle"
        tools:text="Finish filling prep"

        />


    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/image_has_video"
        android:id="@+id/text_step_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_internal_views"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

StepMasterActivity and StepListFragment: Sorry, I cannot attend the SO demand for format, so I create gists:

StepMasterActivity:

https://gist.github.com/alexpfx/2138e7e17cb519b5499b0285f1c0a323

StepListFragment:

https://gist.github.com/alexpfx/e44b5709712fbf601a33f7bb9f80f9e8

---

colors.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#757575</color>
    <color name="white">#FFF</color>
</resources>
```

---

```
styles.xml:

    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>      
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

</resources>
```

[image: tablet image layout]

[image: phone image layout]